# Mechanism for reaction between carboxylic acid and manganese(II) oxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, carbonyl-compounds

I am reading about redox reactions of carboxylic acids with $\ce{MnO}$ but I couldn't find any mechanism online,so can any one provide the mechanism.

[image: Reaction of carboxylic acids with MnO]

Comment: @LightYagami The patent page you linked uses $\ce{MnO2}$ as oxidising agent, not MnO

Comment: Oh, and you'd like a *real* mechanism, or a reaction scheme? The first is most likely unknown. The second you should try to write yourself.